# Eclipse doesn't show any C++ project selection after I install CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, project, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I have had a problem, I installed CDT in eclipse, the installation was successful. However, when I tried a project in C++, there is no selection for C++ Project in **Menu File -> New**. I have tried to find it everywhere but It doesn't show up. I also reinstalled it several times, It still didn't work.
My Eclipse is JUNO
here is the link I add to "Install new software" in help : http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno

Comment: What OS? On ScientificLinux 6+ you have to install eclipse-pdt for cdt to work...

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> New -> Other and find C/C++ projects. Unless you have the C/C++ Perspective view on I don't think C++ projects are offered at the first level under new. Once you actually, start a C++ project, Eclipse will ask if you want to switch to the CDT persepective.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no selection for C/C++ project in File ->new -> Other.